# Acess Value of Combo Box filled by a DataBase (Layered Architecture)

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview, combobox

Folks!

The deal is... I have a layered application, with one i have a method to fill my `combo box` with names of states (that are recorded in my database)

I use it to make a register of clientes, so far so good. 
But, when i try to alter the informations of my clientes, the state is set on the first value of the `combo box` and not the one i had choose before....

Extra Information: The information to alter the cliente comes from a `datagridview` , that is updates afeter the successful register.

I'm filling the `combo box` in my load event.

I'm setting the information that way:

```
cliente.estado = cbEstado.Text;
```

And getting the information:

```
cbEstado.Text = dgvConsulta[8, dgvConsulta.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
```

Thanks for the atention!

Comment: try cbEstado.SelectedValue = dgvConsulta[8, dgvConsulta.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();

Comment: Nops, nothing change.. It's still taking the first value

Comment: are you calling bind combobox after setting value ?

Comment: No, the only thing i have it's the fill method on load, so in the alter button i made that code.

Comment: I would suggest you to add watch of `cbEstado.SelectedValue` and then debug line by line, I hope you will get the problem when the value changes into watch window.